# Formating os samsung galaxy tab 3 SM -T111 without any backup

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab-3-7

While running recovery in TWRP mode, i had formate all my data including my android operating system 4.2 jellybean without any backup. How can i recover my phone OS back?

Answer (score 1):

You can't recover it. You need to find a copy of the stock ROM (probably from sammobile.com, which is a good source for Samsung ROMs), and flash that to the phone.